# Error "install_driver(Oracle) failed" when running Perl script which is pointing to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi, dbd

I am running a Perl script, which is pointing to an Oracle database, which requires an Oracle driver to execute the Perl script.

Below is the error message:

```
“install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't locate DBD/Oracle.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 3) line 3”
```

Could you please advise me to how install the Oracle driver on CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

See the [`INSTALL` file for `DBD::Oracle`](https://metacpan.org/source/MJEVANS/DBD-Oracle-1.80/INSTALL) and [`DBD::Oracle::Troubleshooting`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-Oracle/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting.pod)